# DMS for OpenSearch as target - Nested Type data

Tags: migration, database-migration, opensearch, aws-dms, dms

In Opensearch, we have nestedtype columns like this :

"TextColumn1" : {
"type" : "nested",
"properties" : {
"original" : {
"type" : "text"
},
"lowercase" : {
"type" : "keyword"
}
}

We'll have a DMS which will migrate data from MSSQL to OpenSearch. So for few columns if we want data in target(Opensearch) to be in the nested type (as mentioned above). How to migrate them?

1.Does DMS supports migration of Such Types? It was mentioned in the DMS documentation that it won't support LOB objects. [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Elasticsearch.html)

2.If it supports, how the data should be in MSSQL? (How should we structure the data in MSSQL)

3.If DMS won't support, what would be the workaround for this?

1.Went through with the documentation, didn't get the clear confirmation that whether DMS will support migration of such data.

2.If DMS supports, How to have data in source (MSSQL in our case), so that DMS will index in nested type in target?